# I am trying to make the second bootstrap row fill the remaining height

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an ASP.NET app that connects to a SQL database. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

I would like:

1) My graph to take all the blank space (i.e. second row height)

2) Add padding to the graph, so the date on the right full shows

I must not see the obvious. Thank you for your help!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <link href="css/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/Pikaday/moment.js" type="text/javascript"  ></script>
    <script src="scripts/Pikaday/pikaday.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/nv.d3.min.js"></script>

<style>
.singleLabel{
    min-height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: large;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
.textBox{
    border-left-width: 1px;
    min-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
.textbox.dropDown{
    text-align: right;
}
text {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
}
    html, body, #chart, svg{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%
    width: 100%;
}
.nv-x text{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.nv-y text{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.nv-series text {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.row {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.column{

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div class="row">&emsp;Report from:&emsp;
   <asp:TextBox ID="startDate" runat="server" columns="6" style="border:1px solid #ff0000"></asp:TextBox>
   &emsp;To&emsp;
   <asp:TextBox ID="endDate" runat="server" columns="6" style="border:1px solid #ff0000"></asp:TextBox>
   &emsp;<input type="button" id="btGO" value="Go!" />


   <%-- Date picker for start and end --%>
   <script = "text/javascript">
      var picker = new Pikaday({
           field: document.getElementById("startDate"),
           firstDay: 1,
           format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
           minDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
           maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
           yearRange: [2000,2020],
           numberOfMonths: 2
      });
   </script>

    <script = "text/javascript">
      var picker = new Pikaday({
           field: document.getElementById("endDate"),
           firstDay: 1,
           format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
           minDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
           maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
           yearRange: [2000,2020],
           numberOfMonths: 2
      });
   </script>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div id="chart">
    <svg></svg>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    d3.json('https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3.org/master/ghpages/stackedAreaData.json', function (data) {
        nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                          .x(function (d) { return d[0] })
                          .y(function (d) { return d[1] })
                          .clipEdge(true)
                          .useInteractiveGuideline(true);

            chart.xAxis
                .showMaxMin(true)
                .tickFormat(function (d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });

            chart.yAxis
                .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'));

            d3.select('#chart svg')
              .datum(data)
                .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
        });
    })
</script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for the height something like a fixed value. I think `<div id="chart">` is the chart you want to take up space vertical?

Try in your CSS:

```
div.chart {
    height: 80vh;
}
```

VH stands for viewport height. So it will take 80% of your screens height.

For the row you could just try

```
padding: 0 10px;
```

Or another value, just the padding you like.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed! So simple and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using flexbox.

Flexbox example in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47dL1nxe/)

**Key CSS:**

```
#container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#graph{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Let me know if this helps or if you have any more questions. You will also want to include prefixes as shown [here](http://shouldiprefix.com/#flexbox).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :D